# about post data

Tags: php

everyone.my question like this:

post.php

```
<?php
$str = "testmytest";
$str_serialize = serialize($str);

http_post_fields("get_post.php", array('str' => $str_serialize));
?>
```

get_post.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['str']))
{
  $echo $_POST['str'];

  $str = unserialize($_POST['str']);

  echo $str;
}
?>
```

i can not unserialize the $str, it is changed.who knows why?
Thanks for everybody.

Comment: sorry, it is my mistake about "array('str', $str_serialize)".

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for [`http_post_fields`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php) function:

```
http_post_fields("get_post.php", array('str' => $str_serialize));
```

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter in http_post_fields() should look like this:

```
http_post_fields('get_post.php', array('str' => $str_serialize));
```